# When I run a panel regression it says it is computationally singular...but i don't think it is

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to use [r] to run plm on two large datasets, one with 400K obs and the other with 1.1 million.  I can run the smaller in SAS but the larger doesn't work.  I was trying to see if I could use [r] and when I try to run the code below it always comes back as follows:

```
> pvlag<-read.csv(file="pvlag.csv", sep=",")
>  pvpanel<-plm.data(pvlag, c("New_ID", "billmo"))
 pv<-plm(usetotl~livgarea+yardarea+poolsize+lagavg+lat1+nonlat1+grad+grad,data=pvpanel, model="random", random.method=("swar"), index=c("New_ID", "billmo"))
```

> series    are constants and have been removed Error in
>   solve.default(crossprod(X.m)) :    system is computationally singular:
>   reciprocal condition number = 6.47315e-22

This happens with both data sets, even though when i run the smaller one in SAS it outputs estimated coefficients etc without issue.  Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Also, since I am running a random effects model why would cosntant values be removed?  I thought that was only an issue with fixed effects models?

Comment: Looking at your call I see "grad+grad" in your formula, was that intentional?

Comment: It would be helpful if you submit some sample data so we can reproduce the problem. I myself often realize what I overlooked when I do this.

Comment: Please let us know if this question has been answered appropriately - feel free to write in an answer yourself and check it off.  Thanks for asking a question about plm(), also.

Answer (score 3):

you used the variable *grad* twice. it also happens if you are using dummy variables which would produce 1s over the whole sample, say you have two dummy variables, the first one has a 1 for the first 200K, and the second has a one for the second 200K. you can't use both. you have to choose one - but it does not matter which one.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had fallen into the dummy trap when I got this error. Isn't that your case too?